# Find value that occurs consecutively most nunber of times in array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, loops, time

The following code is in java lang:

```
int[] array = {1,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,1};
int k = 2;
```

What i need to do is find the value (in this case 3), that occurs consecutively more than k times. There can be only one value that `occurs>k` and if no such value exists, `print -1`

Explanation: 
1 occurs only 1 time consecutively. 
2 occurs 2 times but its not>k.
 3 occurs 3 times, which is>k. Since, there can be only one possible answer, you can stop searching for answer in further values and print 3.
The time limit for code is 0.25s

Update : What I've tried so far

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] array = {1,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,1};
        int k=2;
        int result = -1;
        for(int lom =0;lom<array.length-1;lom++){
            int temp = 0;
            int lo=lom;
            while(array[lo]==array[lom]){
                temp+=1;
                if(lo<array.length){lo++;}else{break;}
            }
            if(temp>k){
                result = array[lom];
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

When I try to solve about 10 queries through this, it takes up 2 seconds. I got to complete it in 1. Can you suggest some method to optimize the code, so that I can research upon it and then try again.

Comment: Okay, what have **you** tried so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a cut & pasted assignment without an ounce of effort expended.

Comment: ideone.com/e.js/ZZT3Ay

Comment: I've tried a lot, my code works. The only problem is that it takes a lot of time when I try to solve about 10 queries with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to traverse twice with `while` loop and `lo`

1.) Traverse using loop

2.) If keep a track of element sequence

3.) if element changes , reset track

4.) when the track reaches above `k` break the loop

```
    int[] array = {1,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,1};
    int k = 2;
    // get first element
    int element=array[0];

    // set tot to 1 
    int tot=1;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            // if values are same , increment tot
            if (element==array[i]) {
                tot++;
            }else {
                // set element to new found value and tot = 1
                element=array[i];
                tot=1;
            }
            // when any elements exceeds the k limit 
            // print element and stop the loop
            if (tot>k) {
                System.out.println(array[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
        // to print -1 if tot > k never reached
        if (!(tot>k)) {
            System.out.println(-1);
        }
```